# Curl in php returns 404 response code even if url is working

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, centos6.5

I am using php 5.4 in CentOs 6.5

I am trying to get response code of a url below is my code snippet

```
$URL="http://www.bertuccis.com/#menu";
try{

    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $contents = curl_exec($c);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($c);

    echo 'Resp Code ' . $httpCode;
} catch(Exception $ex){
    print_r($ex);
}
```

It returns 404 Http response code. If i try same url in browser, it returns 200 Ok.

I tried using curl -v on terminal of my centos machine but its working

Here is the version info of curl and php-curl

Curl lib in my centos is : curl 7.24.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.24.0

php-curl info in my php info :

```
cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.19.7
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => Yes
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
Largefile => Yes
NTLM => Yes
SPNEGO => No
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
krb4 => No
libz => Yes
CharConv => No
Protocols => tftp, ftp, telnet, dict, ldap, ldaps, http, file, https, ftps, scp, sftp
Host => x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
SSL Version => NSS/3.15.3
ZLib Version => 1.2.3
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.4.2
```

Comment: Try removing the #menu part and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Styphone  If i will remove #menu from url, it will work But however same url is used for many other purposes too. so i can't modified url given by user

Comment: I get 200 with yout code. (Ubuntu, PHP 5.5, curl 7.35)

Comment: @Gerald , Your Curl version in your system will be same i am having different, you can check using curl -V and php -i on terminal if linux user. if curl -V and php -i shows same version greater that 7.19 than it will give you 200 Ok

Comment: Well, then the solution would be to update curl.

Comment: @Gerald, i tried updating curl for php could not get latest than 7.19 in centos 6.5. I am able to update in Fedora 17 but i need it in CentOs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in curl and fixed on 7.28.1 (according to this page http://curl.haxx.se/changes.html).

Note: Modern browsers doesnt send fragment part at the request. But your curl sending it, this is making difference.